# Rails how to get DB column dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Fellas,

I have a database with columns named line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6.

I have a

```
x = rand(6)+1
```

to get the random value. Now I want the "line"+x somehow like this:

```
y = @variable."line"+x.to_s
```

And get back the data in lineX.
Whats the correct formula? TX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `send` method of `Object`:

```
y = @variable.send("line#{x}")
```

Comment: because of duck typing I accept this. Thank you BOTH of you guys helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an ActiveRecord model for your database table. The following should work:

```
x = rand(6)+1 
@record = MyModel.find(1)
y = @record["line#{x}"]
```